# sql query which will calculate Moving average must exclude zero value rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have been trying to calculate the moving average in sql server for over 60 value period but i didn't succeed, hope you guys help me out.

Please find the data below

```
User       startdate           Enddate           minutes     moving average 
Sync    3/15/2014 10:00     3/15/2014 11:47      107         113.4117647 
Sync    3/15/2014 12:00     3/15/2014 13:45      105         112.8627451
Sync    3/15/2014 14:00     3/15/2014 15:41      101         112.5490196
Sync    3/15/2014 16:00     3/15/2014 17:12      72          112.372549
Sync    3/16/2014 1:00      3/16/2014 1:00       0           112.372549
Sync    3/16/2014 2:00      3/16/2014 2:00       0           112.372549
```

Requirement the query must not consider the rows which were zero even though it should be displayed in the table the above last column is excepted average.

Comment: Could you share with us some (or all) of your code you are using atm for calculating the moving average?

Comment: hello Nicky,my code is not working as i have tried to from different sources hence i raised this question ,in order to get help !! waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I'm not sure how you're getting those moving average values that you've put in your grid, and I'm assuming that they are due to previous values not shown.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
[User] NVARCHAR(10),
[StartDate] DATETIME,
[EndDate] DATETIME,
[Minutes] FLOAT,
[Average] FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @table ([User],[startdate],[Enddate],[minutes]) VALUES 
('Sync','3/15/2014 10:00','3/15/2014 11:47',107.0),
('Sync','3/15/2014 12:00','3/15/2014 13:45',105.0),
('Sync','3/15/2014 14:00','3/15/2014 15:41',101.0),
('Sync','3/15/2014 16:00','3/15/2014 17:12',72.0),
('Sync','3/16/2014 1:00','3/16/2014 1:00',0.0),
('Sync','3/16/2014 2:00','3/16/2014 2:00 ',0.0)

UPDATE t
SET [Average] = [avg]
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  
    [startdate],
    AVG(NULLIF([Minutes],0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [User]  ORDER BY [startdate]) [avg]
  FROM
    @table
) a ON a.StartDate = t.StartDate

SELECT * FROM @table
```

Let me know how you get on.

Stuart

Comment: Hello stuart , i m using sql server 2008 r2 when i try to run the query what you have provided im getting follwing error Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: HEllo stuart i have executed the query im getting the follwin result User StartDate EndDate Minutes Average
Sync 3/15/2014 10:00 3/15/2014 11:47 107 96.25
Sync 3/15/2014 12:00 3/15/2014 13:45 105 96.25
Sync 3/15/2014 14:00 3/15/2014 15:41 101 96.25
Sync 3/15/2014 16:00 3/15/2014 17:12 72 96.25
Sync 3/16/2014 1:00 3/16/2014 1:00 0 96.25
Sync 3/16/2014 2:00 3/16/2014 2:00 0 96.25
here what im excepting is the average is not same for all rows must be moving average for the above example the excepted moving average for 3 fields would Average
107
106
104.3333333
92.66666667
92.66667
92.66667

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were using 2012, and didn't realise yo couldn't order a partition in 2008R2.  The query works fine that I provided in 2012 and you get the numbers you're after.  The only way we can do what you want is in a CTE.  I'll have a look at that and get back to you when I can.  There's examples around to show you how to do it though.

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/rolling-averages-in-sql-server/  See if you can work it out from there.  That's a good example and should be adaptable to your question.